# Does $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)}\cdot{\sin(1/n)}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)}\cdot{\sin(1/n)}$ converge?

i know that $\sin(1/n) \le 1/n.\,\,\,$ but i can't find convergence test to prove it .

Comment: clearly a duplicate.

Comment: Just asking a doubt, can this be done using the graph of sin(1/n)/ln(x)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: limit comparison test to $\sum \dfrac{1}{n \ln(n)}$, and integral test for that.

Answer (score 1):

The series diverges. The bound $\sin(1/n)\le 1/n$ is not useful in this situation because the series $\sum(n\log n)^{-1}$ diverges. We need to bound $n\sin(1/n)$ from below. Since
$$
\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n}\to1
$$
as $n\to\infty$, for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N(\varepsilon)$ such that $n\sin(1/n)>(1-\varepsilon)$ for $n>N(\varepsilon)$. We obtain
$$
\sum_{n=N(\varepsilon)+1}^\infty\frac{\sin(1/n)}{\ln n}=\sum_{n=N(\varepsilon)+1}^\infty\frac{n\sin(1/n)}{n\ln n}>(1-\varepsilon)\sum_{n=N(\varepsilon)+1}^\infty\frac1{n\ln n}.
$$
We have that
$$
\sum_{n=N(\varepsilon)+1}^\infty\frac1{n\ln n}\ge\int_{N(\varepsilon)+1}^\infty\frac1{x\ln x}dx=\lim_{m\to\infty}[\log\log x]_{N(\varepsilon+1)}^m=\infty.
$$
We conclude that the series diverges.